# scrapy - strange csv output and missing requests

Tags: python, scrapy

It would be nice if you could help me improving my code and solve the two following questions:

- one of the ids at the start of the process `['DE101096','AT231']` is ignored
- when crawling with scrapy crawl bot -o result.csv the results a csv in the following form:

transactionID      transactionDate         acq_id                        tra_id

DE101096      2011-02-21 11:05:23.312
DE101096      2011-02-21 11:05:23.312 Anlagenkonto Oxyfuelanlage
DE101096      2011-02-21 11:05:23.312 Anlagenkonto Oxyfuelanlage N ationalkonto – Ausgabe

I would obviously like to have only one row with the transactionID, transactionDate, acq_id and tra_id. I know that this problem obviously hinges on my code which passes transactionID, transactionDate to the item which is duplicated because of the two subsequent request. However I can't find any solution which comes closer to the expected output.

How can I solve the above described problems and how in general could I make my spider more effient. I also tried a rule based approach, but this didn't work out at all.

I am happy for all inputs!

```
import csv

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

from etsbot.items import TransactionItem
from etsbot.middlewares import RandomProxy

class EuetsbotdetSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'euetsbotdet'
    allowed_domains = ['ec.europa.eu']
    start_urls = [
        'http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/transaction.do'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
    #self.data = csv.DictReader(open('/home/...t/items.csv','r'))
    #self.tids = []
    #for self.row in self.data:
    #    self.tids.append(self.row['transactionID'])
    self.tids = ['DE101096','AT231']

    for self.id in self.tids:
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='transactions_maxlength',
            formdata={'transactionID':self.id},
            clickdata={'name': 'search'},callback=self.parseLinks
            )

def parseLinks(self,response):
    lex = LinkExtractor(allow=('http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/singleTransaction.do',),unique=True)
    for l in lex.extract_links(response):
        yield Request(l.url,method='GET',callback=self.parseDetail,)                

def parseDetail(self,response):
    sel  = Selector(response)
    item = TransactionItem()
    item['transactionID']   = sel.xpath('//table/tr/td/input[@name="transactionID"]/@value').extract()
    item['transactionDate'] = sel.xpath('//table/tr/td/input[@name="transactionDate"]/@value').extract()

    lext  = LinkExtractor(unique=True,restrict_xpaths = ('//*[@id="tblTransactionBlocksInformation"]/tr/td[6]/a[@class="resultlink"]'),)        
    for l in lext.extract_links(response):
        yield Request(l.url,method='GET',meta={'item':item},callback=self.parseAccounttr)

    lexa  = LinkExtractor(unique=True,restrict_xpaths = ('//*[@id="tblTransactionBlocksInformation"]/tr/td[7]/a[@class="resultlink"]'),)        
    for l in lexa.extract_links(response):
        yield Request(l.url,method='GET',meta={'item':item},callback=self.parseAccountac)
        yield item         

def parseAccounttr(self,response):
    sel   = Selector(response)
    item  = response.meta['item']
    item['tra_id'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="tblAccountInfoReadonly"]/tr/td/input[@name="identifierInReg"]/@value').extract()
    yield item  

def parseAccountac(self,response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['acq_id'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="tblAccountInfoReadonly"]/tr/td/input[@name="identifierInReg"]/@value').extract()
    yield item
```

**Edit:**

With help of the nice comment by paul trmbrth I rewrote my code. Instead of splitting up the downloads in two groups as I have been doing this in the code above, I am now doing all in one stream. This means when I run crawl spider.py -o now for each transactionID/transactionDate I am having two rows, the first for the "Seller" and the second for the "Buyer". Obviously this information should be in one row. My idea now is to automatically correct this in post-processing i.e. to merge each odd item by transactionID/transactionDate with the subsequent even item (I hope this is clear). But how can I do this?

```
import csv

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

from etsbot.items import TransactionItem
#from etsbot.middlewares import RandomProxy
from etsbot.inline_requests import inline_requests


class EuetsbotdetSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'euetsbotdet'
    allowed_domains = ['ec.europa.eu']
    start_urls = [
        'http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/transaction.do'
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        self.tids = ['DE101096']
        for self.id in self.tids:
            yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='transactions_maxlength',
            formdata={'transactionID': self.id},
            clickdata={'name': 'search'},
            callback=self.parseDetail,
            )


    def parseDetail(self, response):
        lex = LinkExtractor(allow=    ('http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/singleTransaction.do',),unique=True)
        for l in lex.extract_links(response):
            yield Request(l.url, method='GET', callback = self.parseAccount)


    def parseAccount(self, response):
        sel  = Selector(response)
        self.transactionID = sel.xpath('//table/tr/td/input[@name="transactionID"]/@value').extract()
        self.transactionDate = sel.xpath('//table/tr/td/input[@name="transactionDate"]/@value').extract()

        lex  = LinkExtractor(unique=True,restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="tblTransactionBlocksInformation"]/tr/td/a[@class="resultlink"]'),)
        for l in lex.extract_links(response):
            yield Request(l.url,method='GET',callback=self.parseAgents)

    def parseAgents(self,response):
        sel  = Selector(response)
        ag   = sel.xpath('//*[@id="tblAccountInfoReadonly"]/tr/td/input[@name="identifierInReg"]/@value').extract()
        ah   = sel.xpath('//*[@id="tblAccountInfoReadonly"]/tr/td/input[@name="accountHolder"]/@value').extract()
        item = TransactionItem() 
        item['transactionID'] = self.transactionID
        item['transactionDate'] = self.transactionDate
        item['identifierInReg'] = ag
        item['accountHolder'] = ah
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

About the 1st point, when you write:

```
for self.id in self.tids:
    return FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formname='transactions_maxlength',
        formdata={'transactionID':self.id},
        clickdata={'name': 'search'},callback=self.parseLinks
        )
```

the loop stops at the first iteration because you use `return`.

Change it to a "`yield` loop":

```
for self.id in self.tids:
    yield FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formname='transactions_maxlength',
        formdata={'transactionID':self.id},
        clickdata={'name': 'search'},callback=self.parseLinks
        )
```

Regarding the 2nd point, as @EricValente says, if you want 1 CSV row per transaction ID, you'll need to yield/return only 1 item per transaction ID.

You can start building the item in `parseDetail`, and pass this item in `meta`, like you're doing, but then you need to track how many requests are outstanding to know when to return the item when you've processed every response.
This can be quite tricky to do correctly. For example you must catch request failures.
You can try [scrapy-inline-requests](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-inline-requests) which is very handy for this.

Another option is to do the post-processing and grouping by transaction ID after a first scrape, so you build your CSV by hand.

Another option is to not do these extra requests for `parseAccounttr()` and `parseAccountac()`: as far as I can see for at the 2 transaction IDs, the text value of the links in `tr[6]` and `tr[7]` in `parseDetail()` have the same value as the `identifierInReg` attributes you scrape in the subsequent callbacks

Comment: thank you very much, your comment helped me a lot to understand the sequential process better in scrapy. this essentially means the best way would be to collect the data as it is coming in, ignoring if the stuff is coming from tr[6] and tr[7], an post process it in pipelines. i rewrote the code from above accordingly: http://pastebin.com/VBAiStZq but how could i do the processing? so in my case always odd and even rows are supposed to be merged by transactionID I guess .... i could do this in the pipeline right?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code, but the problem is that you are yielding the item 3 times, at different parts of the scrape (which is why each of them contains only a subset of the fields you are looking for).  You need to only have one "yield item" at the end.  I rewrote the code, you can find it at http://pastebin.com/dxsHZ7fZ .

Comment: thank you very much for your help! unfortunately however this doesn't work either. because the second block which extracting the links doesn't take the right response channel. and that is the problem: i have one page with two links which belong to different categories. they should be parsed and treated separately and populate different items.